# BeautifulSoup not extracting specific tag text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem harvesting the information for a specific tag using BeautifulSoup.  I would like to extract the text for 'Item 4' between the tag html, but the code below gets the text related to 'Item 1.'  What am I doing incorrect(e.g., slicing)?

**Code:**

```
primary_detail = page_section.findAll('div', {'class': 'detail-item'})
for item_4 in page_section.find('h3', string='Item 4'):
  if item_4:
    for item_4_content in page_section.find('html'):
      print (item_4_content)
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 1</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 1 text here</p></body></html>
</div>

<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 2</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 2 text here</p></body></html>
</div>

<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 3</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 3 text here</p></body></html>
</div>

<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 4</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 4 text here</p></body></html>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to print the `<p>` tag content according to `<h3>` text value, correct?

Your code must:

1. load a `html_source`
2. search for all `'div'` tags that contains a `'class'` equal to `'detail-item'`
3. for each occurrence, if the `.text` value of `<h3>` tag is equal to the string `'Item 4'`
4. then the code will `print` the `.text` value of the corresponding `<p>` tag

You can achieve what you want by using the following code.

**Code:**

```
s = '''<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 1</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 1 text here</p></body></html>
</div>

<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 2</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 2 text here</p></body></html>
</div>

<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 3</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 3 text here</p></body></html>
</div>

<div class="detail-item">
   <h3>Item 4</h3>
   <html><body><p>Item 4 text here</p></body></html>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

primary_detail = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'detail-item'})

for tag in primary_detail:
    if 'Item 4' in tag.h3.text:
        print(tag.p.text)
```

**Output:**

```
'Item 4 text here'
```

---

**EDIT:** In the [provided website](https://fortiguard.com/psirt/FG-IR-17-097) the first loop occurence don't have a `<h3>` tag, only a `<h2>` so it won't have any `.text` value, correct?

You can bypass this error using a `try/except` clause, like in the following code..

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://fortiguard.com/psirt/FG-IR-17-097'
html_source = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')

primary_detail = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'detail-item'})

for tag in primary_detail:
    try:
        if 'Solutions' in tag.h3.text:
            print(tag.p.text)
    except:
        continue
```

If the code faces an exception, it'll continue the iteration with the next element in the loop. So the code will ignore the first item that don't contain any `.text` value.

**Output:**

```
'Upgrade to FortiWLC-SD version 8.3.0'
```

Comment: I received this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' which is linked to this -- tag.h3.text.

Comment: how did you loaded the html_source? in my example i used the source you provided... but in a real problem you can use something like `s = requests.get(url).text` to load the html source

Comment: Yes, I'm scraping a real page.  I'm able to extract the text from a h2 tag located within the div class="detail-item" tag, but not the text under the h3 tags.  here is the line that I'm using for getting the content of the page - itemSoupParser = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser').  I'm able to get everything from the page, except the h3 text content.

Comment: You should post the url then, because it's working with the sample you provided.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I've updated my answer. Take a look now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142651/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-dot-py).